# Is “Who is he?” ok when we don’t know the sex?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammar, gender-neutral

Suppose I see someone coming whose gender is unknown; how should I ask who the approaching person is? Should I say “Who is he?”

Comment: "Who is that?" is a neutral option.

Comment: If it’s somebody you aren’t quite sure of, you could always wait till they got there and ask them yourself. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Preferably, no. This is a case in which "Who is that?" is entirely acceptable, because the use of "that" reflects the uncertainty of the question itself. "He" is too specific; it offers a part of the answer you are seeking.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not. I am not a native English-speaker, but I would say, “Who is **that person**?” instead of *he*. *He* is supposed to be a “guy”.